# How do I create system logs during authentication?

Tags: logging, symfony4

I was following the guide here and implemented basic authentication system:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

However, I would like to add system logs to my application. To be precise, I would like:

- to be able to insert a record with who successfully logged at what hour
- to be able to record when someone tried to log and failed

I know that I can put logs in my SecurityController, like this:

```
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
    // if ($this->getUser()) {
    //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
    // }

    $log = new Logs();
    $em->persist($log);

    $log->setAction('auth')
        ->setDate(new DateTime())
        ->setIp($request->getClientIp());

    $em->flush();

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
}
```

but it only gives me the information that someone was on the login page. What do I modify or add to get the other info?

Comment: The usual way to have full control over your authentication logic is to implement a [Guard Authenticator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be solve your problem.

You should do it via Symfony events. These 2 events triggering after failed/succeed login attempts: `security.authentication.success` and `security.authentication.failure` .

I will make an example for success and you can apply it for failure:

1. Add this to your `config/service.yml`

   ```
   App\EventListener\SuccessLoginListener:
   tags:
       - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.authentication.success'}
   ```
2. Then you can create the Listener and do it logging process in it

   ```
   namespace App\EventListener;

   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\AuthenticationSuccessEvent;

   class SuccessLoginListener
   {
   private $em;

   public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
   {
       $this->em = $em;
   }

   public function onSecurityAuthenticationSuccess(AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event)
   {
   // TODO: Create your log entity at here.
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it also creates extra logs during the logout operation and when I simply click 'login' button. Any idea how to handle it separately?

Comment: I happy to see this solve your problem. You should check another Symfony security authentication events.